# Get facebook post insights of page on daily basis

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am hitting the following facebook api in graph api explorer to get the daily insights of page post. It always return the empty response.

```
2168960843146707_2213719068670884/insights?metric=page_actions_post_reactions_like_total, page_actions_post_reactions_haha_total,page_actions_post_reactions_wow_total&period=day&since=1550146218&until=1550148280
```

[image: Facebook graph api]

Comment: All those metrics you are trying to request there are on the page level - that’s why their names all start with `page_`

Comment: I am not asking about the page prefix with the metrics field. I just want to know how i  get the insights of a post created on page on daily basis. For example how many likes the post had on Feb 20 or other days.

Comment: If you want metrics on the basis of a single post, then you need to use metrics with names starting with `post_`, not `page_`.

Comment: If I set the metrices with "post_" prefix, then It gives me the response. But that is not the daily basis response. As I have discussed above.

Comment: Most of the post-based metrics are not available on a daily basis, but only for the lifetime period. _As explained in the documentation._

Answer (score 0):

There is either no data for those fields, or your page didn't meet certain criteria. You're also querying for a 30 minute time range for yesterday, so those metrics may not be ready yet, but I think they probably should be if your page is published.

"Insights are only generated for a Facebook Page that has more than 100 people that like it. Likewise, demographic metrics, such as age, gender and location, are available in Page Insights once there is data for 100 or more people."